# How can I mock execution of coroutines using mockk?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines, mockk

I'm trying to use the `mockk` framework to set up a mock in one of my unit tests that executes a suspending function like this:

```
val executionCompletionSource = CompletableDeferred<Nothing>()
suspend fun task(): Unit = executionCompletionSource.await()
val mock = mockk<Executable> { coEvery { execute() } coAnswers { task() } }
```

However, I find that the test hangs indefinitely if I call `mock.execute()` in a launched coroutine scope. If I call `task()` directly within the launched scope instead, the test runs fine.

Although the [mockk documentation](https://github.com/mockk/mockk#coroutines) does talk a little about coroutine mocking, I can't find any documentation or examples showing how to execute coroutines in response to calling a suspending function on a mock.

Here's an SSCCE demonstrating this:

```
package experiment

import io.mockk.coEvery
import io.mockk.mockk
import kotlinx.coroutines.CompletableDeferred
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis

interface Executable {
    suspend fun execute()
}

fun main() {
    val executionCompletionSource = CompletableDeferred<Nothing>()
    suspend fun task(): Unit = executionCompletionSource.await()
    val mock = mockk<Executable> { coEvery { execute() } coAnswers { task() } }

    runBlocking {
        val execution = launch { mock.execute() } // This blocks the test indefinitely
        //val execution = launch { task() } // This works fine (~110-120 ms)
        measureTimeMillis {
            delay(100)
            executionCompletionSource.cancel()
            execution.join()
        }.also { elapsed -> println("Elapsed in $elapsed ms") }
    }
}
```

The following dependencies are used:

```gradle
implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.0")
implementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.8.10.kotlin13")
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be bug with the way mockk handles coroutines - it's now being [tracked here](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/171).

As a temporary workaround I'm manually creating mocks in cases where I need to mock suspend functions. For example:

```
private fun generateDummyChildren(
    numberOfChildren: Int = 5 /* sensible default */,
    executionRoutine: suspend () -> Unit
): Iterable<ExecutableNode> {
    fun createDummy(index: Int) = object: ExecutableNode {
        override val id = "Dummy $index"
        override suspend fun execute() = executionRoutine()
    }

    return Array(numberOfChildren, ::createDummy).asIterable()
}
```

Comment: This is already fixed in master. Soon there will be a release